# jQuery.browser: Javascript Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, typeerror

I'm experiencing an error which wont let my page load.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

The error in the console refer to this code:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    extra_px += 3;
                                                   // Fix Link Clicking on IE 7 and below versions
if (jQuery.browser.msie && Number($.browser.version) < 8) {
    span_text.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    span_text.click(function() {
        window.location = menu_item.parent().attr("href");
    });
}
```

The weird thing is that it suddenly happened, I didn't change a thing. For reference, I'm using Wordpress.

Comment: try if the value is defined via typeof(jQuery.browser.msie)!='undefined

Comment: same error with = typeof(jQuery.browser.msie)!='undefined'

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded? What's the output of `console.log( typeof jQuery );`?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined` means that `jQuery.browser` is not defined.

Comment: @FelixKling which is not true in the jQuery version used by SO

Comment: console output = undefined

Comment: my website is tranceil.fm

Comment: @TonalDev how are you trying to include jQuery on the wordpress side?

Comment: @Jan: Nor in any other version I tested... but still, that's what the error means.

Comment: if `typeof jQuery == 'undefined'`, then it seems your jQuery source is dead.

Comment: I'm including it on the header...(i must say that jquery is loaded somewhere in wordpress but if i didnt include it manually, other things got broken)

Comment: Issue seems to be with the jQuery loading, try refreshing the page.

Comment: @Jan: If `jQuery` was `undefined` you would get the error `Cannot read property 'browser' of undefined`. Anyways, VisioN found the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *jQuery.browser* was *deprecated* in version 1.3, and finally **removed** in
>   1.9.

<sub>[source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jquerybrowser-is-deprecated)</sub>

As you can see in [current version of jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js), there is no `$.browser` property anymore.

Most probably it was moved to plugin as was stated in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

So if you use the very last version of jQuery, the `undefined` error is understandable.

Comment: OP shouldn't include the latest version but a specific version

Comment: @ExplosionPills and yet he likely does

Comment: @JanDvorak he does; I looked at his website's code.  He includes 1.8.3 via wordpress, but then he also includes a link to the jQuery cdn for the latest version

Comment: The 1.8.3 file breaks thing so i had to include the latest for things to work..i still havent found the location from which the devloper loaded the file.

Comment: 1.8.3 _is_ the latest version

Comment: VisioN answer was correct...i referred to the 1.8.3 Ver'...and it worked.

Comment: @JanDvorak for whatever reason they updated the CDN to point to 1.9, but the other jQuery websites aren't updated (the documentation isn't and jquery.com still says the "current release" is 1.8.3).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, jQuery.browser was deprecated in older version and removed in 1.9.So  Now In old version if code written like this

```
isIE6 = jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 7 && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
```

will be replaced it by

```
isIE6 = navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6]/i) && !window.XMLHttpRequest,
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

As [VisioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249581/vision)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337859/jquery-browser-javascript-uncaught-typeerror#14338019) mentions, this was removed in jQuery 1.9 and isn't coming back anytime soon, it seems.

If you would like working Plugin to reAdd `$.browser` to your jQuery library, simply copy & paste the code below to a file and link the script in anywhere after jQuery:

```
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
```

## *jsFiddle*

---

Use traditionally like: `if ($.browser.msie) { doWork }`

---

```js
/** jQuery.browser
 * @author J.D. McKinstry (2014)
 * @description Made to replicate older jQuery.browser command in jQuery versions 1.9+
 * @see http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/wsqfbe4s/
 *
 * @extends jQuery
 * @namespace jQuery.browser
 * @example jQuery.browser.browser == 'browserNameInLowerCase'
 * @example jQuery.browser.version
 * @example jQuery.browser.mobile @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser['browserNameInLowerCase']
 * @example jQuery.browser.chrome @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.safari @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.opera @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.msie @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.mozilla @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.webkit @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.ua @returns navigator.userAgent String
 */
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

var b = $.browser;
console.log($.browser);    //    see console, working example of jQuery Plugin
console.log($.browser.chrome);

for (var x in b) {
    if (x != 'init')
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<th />', { text: x }),
            $('<td />', { text: b[x] })
        ).appendTo($('table'));
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: .25em .5em; vertical-align: top; }
th { text-align: right; }

textarea { height: 500px; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase() throws an undefined error. If I take the .toLowerCase() out, it works!

Comment: Thanks anyway. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery.Migrate library for deprecated function support like $.browser.

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme