# jQuery latest $.browser

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is jQuery $.browser Deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated)

Did the latest jQuery library change `$.browser`?
When i [run this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/taKm4/) in firefox, im getting an error in console:`TypeError: obj is undefined`

Comment: from their API: `version deprecated: 1.3, removed: 1.9`. `$.support()` can be used instead to detect *some* browser features...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14337859/1249581.

Comment: It can help- **if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 ) {
       //it is IE
    
    } else {
    // firefox, chrome etc.

    }**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was deprecated for a long while. And has been removed since 1.9.

To still be able to use the `$.browser` you should add the following JS, or visit the project on [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

See the version 1.9 changelog:
http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

More info on upgrading
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/). [jQuery.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was deprecated in 1.3 and removed in 1.9. Please read the [upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Per the **[jQuery 1.8 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/)** and **[ticket 9835](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9385)** it's been officially deprecated.