# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.browser.msie')

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery latest $.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505301/jquery-latest-browser)

There was an error with jQuery 1.9 and $.browser; It returns 'undefined' for any $.browser; function. What i did wrong?

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.browser.msie')

I use following code:

```
setTimeout(function(){if($.browser.msie){$('.ovy').animate({top:"0"},ct);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$.browser` have been [removed from 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed). You can use [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to have `$.browser` support.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this problem like this

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1){
    // Only MSIE will evaluate this code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`$.browser` has been removed as of jQuery 1.9](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/). If you want to continue making use of it, you'll need to use the jQuery [`migrate`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) plugin.

Comment: deprecated since 1.4, removed in 1.9