# jQuery migration from 1.8.3 to 1.9.1 stops working in one line, and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, migration, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.8

I was using this code:

```
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/
```

And it worked fine with jQuery 1.8.3.

Now I changed to jQuery 1.9.1 and it stopped working

Most of my other codes had problems, mostly I had to change .live for .on and it was solved (I don’t know if this was the right thing to do), but with this code, I don’t find the issue.

THIS LINE SEEMS TO GIVE THE PROBLEM:

```
// IE6 Fix
var pos = ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) ? 'absolute' : 'fixed';
```

You can test it in jsFiddle and you can change to jQuery 1.8.3, to see how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/P8sfn/1/

Comment: Please research when you upgrade. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/) and call the `$.browser`. It will work!

Using the plugin is easy; just include it immediately after the script tag for jQuery, for example.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$.each($.browser, function(i, val) {
  $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
  .appendTo( document.body );
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hcgtr/) (See Migrate 1.1.0 check box is checked on left side)

Answer (score 6):

`$.browser` was deprecated in jQuery 1.3 and removed in 1.9.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

You should use the [jQuery migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) to see any errors when migrating to 1.9x. Also, jQuery recommends using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.

Answer (score 0):

$.browser has been removed from 1.9. You can use jQuery Migrate to have $.browser support.

See previously: [TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.browser.msie')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518300/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-browser-msie)

Answer (score 0):

Use feature detection.

```
var someEl = $("#theid");
someEl.css("position","fixed");
if ( someEl.css("position") == "static" ) {
    // doesn't support fixed, use absolute
    someEl.css("position","absolute");
}
```

(not tested)