# jQuery $.browser is undefined. Tried other solutions but did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are currently using 1.9.1 but the jQuery [Swappable](http://www.eslinstructor.net/demo/swappable/swappable_grid.html) functionality I'm using is 1.7.2.
I found out that it is deprecated in 1.9.1.

I already tried other solutions like https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme and [jQuery latest $.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505301/jquery-latest-browser) but it did not work.

How can I make it work? Thanks.

Firebug Error:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
if ($.browser.msie && !(document.documentMode >= 9) && !event.button) {
```

Comment: It was in fact deprecated in 1.3, and removed in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: Yes Qantas, I'm aware of that. But how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: So are you saying that you'd like to upgrade your jQuery code to 1.9.1 but still be able to detect old versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: I'm currently using version 1.9.1 and the swappable functionality that I would like to use uses the 1.7.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Possible not the best way to go about it but you can use multiple versions of jQuery with `noConflict` view [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) for more details.

The swappable plugin that you are using seems to use jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.21 So even if you managed to fix the `$.browser` problem there is always the possibility that some other issue pops up while using the library because the library does not support 1.9.1

Comment: Thanks DGS. I will try it now. Hopeful that it might fix my issue. Will update you on this.

Comment: Hi DGS, unfortunately it did not work. We'll just change the functionality with a similar one for now while finding a way to solve this problem *sigh*

Comment: when using noConflict did you use `$` as the identifier for the 1.7.2 version of jQuery?

Comment: Yes. It is still the same. Are there any jQuery swappable plugin out there that uses the latest jQuery version for at least 1.9.1? I can't find one in google. Thanks