# $.browser is undefined error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-1.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is jQuery $.browser Deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated)
>   [jQuery latest $.browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505301/jquery-latest-browser)

In a code I am using JQuery is loading. I have gone through all the files that should be loaded, but I can't find where JQuery is loaded. 
I need to include a second JQuery-script in order that a file which I include should work properly, since the first script is loading to late.
However, this leads to other errors, since definitions are overwritten when the first JQuery-file is loading (the one I haven't declared).
So now I am trying to use jQuery.noConflict in order to fix this.

Here are some example of usages in my code:

```
<script>
var $jquery190 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>


jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {
//$(function() {
// more code using $ as alias to jQuery
//});
 $.fn.setupSpinner = function () {
        $(this)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
            })
        ;
        return this;
    };


})(jQuery);


$jquery190(config.ids.datepicker + ", " + config.ids.todatepicker).datepicker("disable");
$jquery190(config.ids.datepicker + ", " + config.ids.todatepicker).datepicker("setDate", "-2d");
$jquery190(config.ids.datepicker + ", " + config.ids.todatepicker).datepicker("enable");
//        $(config.ids.datepicker + ", " + config.ids.todatepicker).datepicker("hide");
```

After doing some of these replacements I get the error:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

...= buttonPanel + ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version,10) < 7 && !inst.i...
```

The website is found here: [Link](http://www.roros.kommune.no/Politikk/Postliste/Journalpost-info1/)
What is the cause of this and how do I resolve this?

Comment: *"What is the cause of this and how do I resolve this?"* jQuery 1.9 is the cause, since `$.browser` was removed in this version. Either use an older version or don't use `$.browser`, respectively, don't use a plugin that uses it. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14337859/1249581.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The .browser call has been removed in jquery 1.9
have a look at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ for more details.

Comment: so what will be the solution for this?

Comment: Use https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme This will restore deprecated functions.