# jquery stopped working, on mine rails app, after adding mercury gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

The error a resive is:
TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined

In my aplication.js file a have

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require mercury
   //= require_self
```

my gem file looks like

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
end


gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem "paperclip"
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem "haml"
gem 'mercury-rails'

group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
end
```

and in my mercury.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'mercury' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7', 'mercury' %>
```

I have the same problem now, even after removing //=require mercury from aplicarion.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.browser is undefined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524289/browser-is-undefined-error)

It appears that your version of jQuery is too new. jQuery.browser is no longer supported. Also the reason the problem persists even after you remove the "//=require mercury" line is because you need to restart your server for the asset pipeline to do its stuff.

Comment: thank you Chris. But mercury gem goes with <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7', 'mercury' %> but it seems not working. And the issue was for Heroku hosting, after I moved to mine, new VPS, the error stay showing in, for example, firebug, but the functionality is fine :)