# Javascript console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I wanted to optimize my page loads recently so I switched from regular javascript files to ones that are minimized. They all work fine except for this one jquery.ui files. When I switched my ui file to one that's minimized, I get an error in chrome's javascript console that reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error because before I switched from the regualar jquery.ui to the minimized one, it was working just fine.

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Are you using the correct version for you jQuery version? Which one are you using?

Comment: @FelixKling [1.9.1](http://sportannica.com/js/jquery.latest.js), while jQuery UI is [1.8.9](http://sportannica.com/js/ui/ui/minified/jquery.ui.core.min.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that in **jQuery 1.9** property [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was removed.

You should update your minimized *jQuery UI* to be compatible with new version of jQuery.

**REF:** [jQuery.browser: Javascript Uncaught TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337859/jquery-browser-javascript-uncaught-typeerror/14338019#14338019)

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery 1.9.1, which [no longer includes the `jQuery.browser` property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/). You'll either need to switch back to an older version of jQuery (< 1.9), or use the [migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is referencing `$.browser`, which is `undefined`. Your minimized UI file is clearly for use with an older version of jQuery .