# TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery mobile 1.4.2 and script 1.11.0

I have read previously asked questions about this but i didn't get how to use in my code.

This is my code

### script

```
jQuery("input[name^='cat']").bind(jQuery.browser.msie ? 'click' : 'change', function(event) {   
var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
mantener_seleccion(id);//its a function name
 });
```

if i run this its showing error like this "TypeError: jQuery.browser is undefined"
Please any one help me in this.

Comment: jQuery.browser is deprecated. **This property was removed in jQuery 1.9**

Comment: Is their any solution to replace this code with some other code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.browser: Javascript Uncaught TypeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337859/jquery-browser-javascript-uncaught-typeerror)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> jQuery.browser is deprecated. **This property was removed in jQuery 1.9**

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45HZH/1/)**

Use **[`navigation.userAgent`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml)**

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf('MSIE') >= 0){
    alert("IE")
}
```

Use this snippet:

```
var isIE = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf('MSIE') >=0 ? 'click' : 'change' ;

jQuery("input[name^='cat']").bind(isIE , function(event) {   
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    mantener_seleccion(id);//its a function name
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply add following script in your code.work for me.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Please Refer this link for more info. https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/469

Comment: This doesn't work when you're working over a secure connection, the browser will filter it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ankur Modi's answer works, but I'm going to add one for the use case where you're working over a secure connection.

Browsers will filter out mixed content over secure connections, so you'll need to import the JS migrate 1.0.0 manually and install it. In my use-case we're using ASP.Net MVC 5x with a mishmash of older JS widgets.

1. Install JS migrate with the NuGet package manager. I installed 1.0.0, as that solved my problem. Newer versions didn't solve my specific problem.
2. In BundleConfig.cs add the line:

   ```
           bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqmigrate").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"));
   ```
3. In _Layout.cshtml add the following line to the bottom of the 'Scripts.Render' section:

   ```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqmigrate")
   ```

   You should now no longer receive the error.

Comment: How does this answer the question?