# Getting "TypeError: a.browser is undefined" when using jquery-1.8.2 and jquery-ui-2.1.3

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to implement mefafolio with version of jquery 2.1.3 and jquery 1.8.2 but I am getting this error "TypeError: a.browser is undefined". Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.browser is deprecated. This property was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379212/typeerror-jquery-browser-is-undefined)