# JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated and cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to migrate my JQuery version from 1.3.2 to 3.5.1. For this I am migrating JQuery from 1.3.0 to 1.12.4. and then to 3.0.0.
But issue is , while migrating to 1.12.4 it show warning as 'browser is deprecated' with no exception. And after migrating to 3.0.0, it is installed successfully.

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.0
But it throws exception in jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js.

**jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined**

Please suggest what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade your jQuery-UI-1.7.3 version, you can patch this by adding the following "shim" function to the very top of your `jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js` file. Or put it elsewhere, as long as it loads before `jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js`.

```
// patch deprecated $.browser
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
```

(Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206540/ for this.)